# Don't show a field if it is not filled in

Tags: theming

What is the best way to don't show up a field if it is not filled in.

I have a content-type for the homepage: (Machine name: home_pagina).

There is a field for my client to give a warning-message if necessary: (Machine name: field_aandachts_tekst).

The warning message has to show up in a colored box/div. But if the field is not filled in, the box/div should not show up.

I tried to achieve this with a field-template....

I already have a "field.tpl.php" created. So i thought if a create a special field template for the field (field_aandachts_tekst) i could put the colored box/div in there. And if the field is not filled in the box/div would not show up also.

But it seems that the field-template for the (field_aandachts_tekst) is not used...

My template for controlling the view of the (field_aandachts_tekst) is called:

field--field-aandachts-tekst.php

but it seems this template is not used... (instead it uses: "field.tpl.php")

The code in my "node--home_pagina.tpl.php" looks like this:

print render($content['field_aandachts_tekst']); surrounded with php-tag ofcourse

Any tips or suggestions are good!

Thanks,
Kristof

Answer (score 0):

Okay dear readers,

I find the solution/problem:

I forgot the extension .tpl in my template name. Stupid of me. Everything is working fine now.

Thanks for reading!

kristof